# Having some issues Sending Mails Using PHP

Tags: php, html, email

I am creating my website. I am giving the options for the user to send the mail to me. I am using php for sending the mails. My Code:

HTML:

```
<form action="mailer.php" method="POST" >

 <input name="name" type="text"  placeholder="Name" required="required">
 <input name="phone_number" type="text"  placeholder="Phone No." required="required">
 <input name="email" type="email"  placeholder="E-Mail" required="required">
 <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send"  >
</form>
```

Mailer.php:

```
<?php
if (isset($_REQUEST['email']))
  {
      $email = $_REQUEST['email'] ;
      $name = $_REQUEST['name'] ;
      $phone=$_REQUEST['phone'] ;         
      mail("priya@gmail.com", $name,
      $phone,   "From:" . $email);
      echo "Thank you for using our mail form";
      }
  }
?>
```

This code is working fine. When i try to add some more parameters it is not sending the mail and gives the warnings.with more parameters i tried like this:

```
      $email = $_REQUEST['email'] ;
      $name = $_REQUEST['name'] ;
      $phone_number = $_REQUEST['phone_number'] ;
      $nationality=$_REQUEST['nationality'] ;
      $itinerary_no=$_REQUEST['itinerary_no'] ;
      $date=$_REQUEST['date'] ;
      mail("sunanth@fairmount.in", $name,
      $phone_number, $nationality, $itinerary_no,$date, "From:" . $email);
```

It gives the warning like this

Warning: mail() [function.mail]: "sendmail_from" not set in php.ini or custom "From:" header missing in \PDC2\sites\f\fairmount.in\public_html\FM\mailer.php

It also gives the error like More than 5 parameters are not allowed. I dont know how to fix this. Totally i am want to send 10 fields  data.

Can anyone help me in this

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation of the `mail()` function? Each argument has a specific purpose, you can't just add lots of data arguments like that.

Comment: Create a string that combines all the data fields, and send that as the message body.

Comment: I hope you will validate the input you get from the form in the final code. The way you write the code right, could allow to use your script to submit spam.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The signature of [mail](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) function is:

> bool mail ( string $to , string $subject , string $message [, string
>   $additional_headers [, string $additional_parameters ]] )

The fourth parameter in the `mail` function is [`additional_headers`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) which is a string that contains extra header information such as `From, Cc, and Bcc)`.  And when you have this fourth parameter you **must** send in the `From` header which is missing in your `mail()` call and hence the error.

So updating your `mail()` method call (with extra variables to show what each parameter is) to following should get you what you are trying to do:

```
$to = "sunanth@fairmout.in";
$subject = "Subject line...";
$message = $name . "\r\n" . $phone_number . "\r\n" . $nationality . "\r\n" . $itinerary_no . "\r\n" . $date;
$headers = "From: $email";

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are passing the extra parameters into the function. This isn't how functions work.

You need to build a string for the message parameter:

`mail("email@blah.com", $name . " " . $phone . " " . $nationality);`

, splits up parameters. . concat's strings.

Comment: php uses `.` not `+` to concat.